# how to CreateSqlFilter between two textbox in one column

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview

now i use this code to make the filter in datagridview

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand();

        var filterConditions = new[] {
    CreateSqlFilter("Name_Arabic", txtName_Arabic, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("gender", CBgender, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("CIVILIDD", txtCIVILIDD, selectCommand, true),
    CreateSqlFilter("status", comboBox1, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("username", txtusername, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("City", comboBoxCity, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("Governorate", comboBoxGovernorate, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("confirmation", comboBox2, selectCommand, false),
    CreateSqlFilter("NATIONALITY", CBNATIONALITY, selectCommand, false)
    // etc.
};

        string filterCondition = filterConditions.Any(a => a != null) ? filterConditions.Where(a => a != null).Aggregate((filter1, filter2) => String.Format("{0} AND {1}", filter1, filter2)) : (string)null;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my"].ConnectionString))
        {
            selectCommand.Connection = connection;
            selectCommand.CommandText = filterCondition == null ? "SELECT * FROM tabl2" : "SELECT * FROM tabl2 WHERE " + filterCondition;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataSource);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
        }
    }

    private string CreateSqlFilter(string fieldName, Control userInputControl, SqlCommand command, bool exactMatch)
    {
        string searchValue = null;
        if (userInputControl is TextBox) searchValue = ((TextBox)userInputControl).Text;
        if (userInputControl is ComboBox) searchValue = ((ComboBox)userInputControl).Text;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue)) return null;

        if (exactMatch)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName, searchValue));
            return fieldName + " = @" + fieldName;
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName, "%" + searchValue + "%"));
            return fieldName + " LIKE @" + fieldName;
        }
    }
```

i want to add two textbox to them to filter in the same column ( age ) what i looking for is filter between two age like between 20 and 30 year old how to add them to my code
[image: my form look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's clear for you that eventually you need one of these SQL conditions:

```
age BETWEEN @ageFrom AND @ageTo
// OR
age >= @ageFrom AND age <= @ageTo
```

But I don't recommend you to extend your `CreateSqlFilter` method because making everything universal is not a good practice. You can simply create another method that will build your filter condition.

Also I suggest you to remove `Control userInputControl` parameter from your query builder and accept `string value` instead. This will make your method independent of WinForms namespace.

**UPDATE**

```
CreateRangeSqlFilter("age", tbAgeFrom.Text, tbAgeTo.Text, selectCommand),

private string CreateRangeSqlFilter(string fieldName, string from, string to, SqlCommand command)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName + "From", from));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName + "To", to));
    return $"{fieldName} BETWEEN @{fieldName}From AND @{fieldName}To";
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
 private string CreateSqlFilter(string fieldName, Control userInputControl, SqlCommand command, bool exactMatch,
     bool isRange = false, Control userInputControl2 = null)
 {
     if (isRange)
     {
         string searchValue1 = null;
         if (userInputControl is TextBox) searchValue1 = ((TextBox)userInputControl).Text;
         if (userInputControl is ComboBox) searchValue1 = ((ComboBox)userInputControl).Text;

         string searchValue2 = null;
         if (userInputControl2 is TextBox) searchValue2 = ((TextBox)userInputControl2).Text;
         if (userInputControl2 is ComboBox) searchValue2 = ((ComboBox)userInputControl2).Text;
         if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue1) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue2)) return null;

         if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue1) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue2))
         {
             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName + "From", searchValue1));
             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName + "To", searchValue2));
             return $"{fieldName} BETWEEN @{fieldName}From AND @{fieldName}To";
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue1))
         {
             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName + "From", searchValue1));
             return $"{fieldName} >= @{fieldName}From";
         }

         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName + "To", searchValue2));
         return $"{fieldName} <= @{fieldName}To";
     }

     string searchValue = null;
     if (userInputControl is TextBox) searchValue = ((TextBox)userInputControl).Text;
     if (userInputControl is ComboBox) searchValue = ((ComboBox)userInputControl).Text;
     if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue)) return null;

     if (exactMatch)
     {
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName, searchValue));
         return fieldName + " = @" + fieldName;
     }
     else
     {
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName, "%" + searchValue + "%"));
         return fieldName + " LIKE @" + fieldName;
     }
 }
```

Comment: if i want to extend it What is the way to add it

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm against that. Create a copy of `CreateSqlFilter` method and name it like `CreateRangeSqlFilter`. Then modify it appropriately (accept `ageFrom` and `ageTo` values  and generate SQL condition)

Comment: sorry bout i still didn't know how to do it

Comment: @AhmedAlKhteeb see example in my post

Comment: thx bout i can do your example I want to add it to my code is there any way for that ??

Comment: I have a problem I need to choose the age to work if the age is not set does not work

Comment: @AhmedAlKhteeb did a quick change there

Comment: where is the change i didn't find it ?

Comment: @AhmedAlKhteeb see it in Update 2 section. The usage is `CreateSqlFilter("age", tbAgeFrom, selectCommand, false, true, tbAgeTo)`

Answer (score 0):

there are two different way to do this without executing query each time.

Highlight:

[image]

Filter:

[image]

Full source code available at:
https://github.com/KohrAhr/XTask/blob/master/Wpf.MainApp/Functions/Functions.DataGrid.cs